Have Vaishnavas narrowed the meaning of "Pashandi" to mean those who don't subscribe to Harisarvottamatvam?
Here is a comment from HSE
Who is a pasandi?

ISKCON does not use the word to describe ''devotees of demigods'', but "heretic" or one whose beliefs are opposed to the scripture. For example a pashandi is one who thinks that the gods Brahma and Shiva are at the same level as Lord Vishnu, which is said in the Padma purana. Lord Vishnu is superior to them, and someone who does not recognize that is a pashandi. –
brahma jijnasa
CommentedAug 16, 2017 at 22:35

The PadmaPurana reference is most likely non-existent

Most of the quotes by Gaudiyas from Padma Purana are wrong references, including that mayavadam asat sastram verse. Neither Ramanujacharya nor Madhwacharya as far as I know quoted the mayavadam asat sastram verse

It takes a lot to express such ideas at HSE.  Thank you @CracklingCyclone

@CracklingCyclone - I see that you have been taking the time to edit many questions recently. Thank you! I hope you keep at it. If you've got the time, would you also take some time to go through the review queues, particularly the one for question-closure? There are many questions that need to be evaluated, and very few users who take the time to do that.
